# How to make a velocimeter-style plot in Python?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

This is what I'm going for:

[image: velocimeter]

Is there anything in, say, Matplotlib that can achieve this? I've looked at the Matplotlib gallery, but couldn't find anything that looks like it.

Comment: Check out these solutions for [matplotlib](http://nicolasfauchereau.github.io/climatecode/posts/drawing-a-gauge-with-matplotlib/) and [plotly](https://plot.ly/python/gauge-charts/)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to plot this image using matplotlib, but, if you are using python, there is an interesting solution using plotly.

These code plot the following image:

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
current_value = 73
min_value = 0
max_value = 100 
fig = go.Figure(go.Indicator(
   mode = "gauge+number",
   value = current_value,
   gauge = {'axis': {'range': [min_value, max_value]},
            'bar': {'color': "darkblue"},
            'steps' : [
                {'range': [0, 50], 'color': "yellow"},
                {'range': [50, 80], 'color': "red"}],},
   domain = {'x': [0, 1], 'y': [0, 1]},
   title = {'text': "Speed"}))
fig.show()
```

[image]

You can check this link for more details:
https://plotly.com/python/gauge-charts/